# Postgres pg dump using pgpass

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'd like to run a command line to dump a schema from a Postgres database (version 9.6) into a backupfile. The issue I'm having at the moment is the command line is not picking up the password from the `pgpass.conf` file and prompting for this.

Let's just say I'm running the following command line using my admin account "cl_admin"

```
 c:\Users\cl_admin>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump.exe"  -h localhost -U pg_admin -w -p 5432 -n finance -F c -b -v -f "C:\TEMP\finance.bac" my_database
```

Running this command line returns the following response:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "my_database" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

If I run the dump command and strip out the '-w' parameter I am prompted for the password and the dump file is generated successfully.

I have saved a copy of the `pgpass.conf` file with the correct credentials to the following directory as stated in Postgres documentation

```
C:\Users\cl_admin\AppData\postgresql
```

pgpass.conf configuration:

```
localhost:5432:my_database:pg_admin:password
```

Thanks you in advance

Comment: The file location should be `C:\Users\cl_admin\AppData\Roaming\postgresql` (actually `%APPDATA%\postgresql`)

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried that but still to no avail?

Comment: What happens when you enter `type %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` on the command line?

Comment: That open the pgpass.conf file in notepad.

Comment: `type` won't open a file, but apparently the file does exist. Does `set  PGPASSFILE` display anything?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. This command returns the location of the PGPASS file `PGPASSFILE=C:\Users\cl_admin\AppData\Roaming\postgresql`

Comment: Does it work if you unset `PGPASSFILE`?

Comment: how do I unset this?

Comment: Hi, I have managed to unset the PGPASSFILE variable so that now when I type 'SET PGPASSFILE'  it returns the following 'Environment variable PGPASSFILE not defined'